# Finding and proving a basis for $W=\{f(x) \in P_2[\mathbb{R} ]:f'(x) +xf(0) = 0 \}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a trouble proving/finding a basis for $W= \{f(x) \in P_2[\mathbb{R}]:f'(x) +x \bullet f(0) = 0 \}$. I'm supposing $\{ x, 1 \}$ is a basis for W because any vector in $P_2[\mathbb{R}]$ gets mapped to $P_1[\mathbb{R}]$ in some form of $ax+b=0$. I just guessed at a basis but how would I find it computationally in the way that is possible for a system of linear equations. Not sure how I should map it to a linear system. If take a system $1a_1 + 1a_2 = 0$ and solve for $a_1$ I get a basis of $\{-1, x \}$ but isn't that the same span anyway? Also what's really got me nailed is how do I express that the basis spans W? Can I just say the basis is linearly independent and has carnality equal the dimension of $W$?

My brain won't let go of this so any help would be greatly appreciated so I can do some other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any element $f(x)$ of $P_2[\mathbb{R}]$ has the form $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c.$  If we write the condition $f'(x)+f(0)x=0$ we get $2ax+b+cx=0,$ that is, $c=-2a,b=0.$ So, any element of $W$ is of the form $ax^2-2a.$ That is, $W$ has dimension one and $\{x^2-2\}$ is a basis of $W$.

Comment: Ok after a series of what, what, what... I think I get it. The basis in this case is composed of some scalar multiple of an element in the domain. So when we look for a basis of a linear transformation we have to look at the domain not the image?

Comment: Yes. $W$ is a subspace of $P_2[\mathbb{R}]$ and here is where you have to look for a basis. Also, you can think of the condition as a linear map $P_2[\mathbb{R}]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and studying the dimension of the kernel (which is $W$) and the image you can get the dimension of $W$ and then look for a basis.

Comment: I've been meditating on this. I know now I can work with
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
But I don't quite understand what this operator is working between in term of a linear map. I just know I row reduce to get a vector equation that gives me results I can use to get a basis for W. But I'm confused as to how W is the kernel. Are you saying I'm mapping W to R?

Comment: No. The kernel $W$ is the set of vectors $(a,b,c)$ satisfying $A(a,b,c)=(0,0,0),$ where $A$ is the matrix that you have written. So $\dim W=3-rank (A)$ and solving the linear system $A(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ you get $W$ and you can pick up a basis. I have made a mistake in the previous comment and it is a map $P_2[\mathbb{R}]\rightarrow P_1[\mathbb{R}]$ or $P_2[\mathbb{R}]\rightarrow P_2[\mathbb{R}]$ as you have written.

Comment: So upon more mediation, can we call the above matrix the left-multiplication transformation, where $F^n$ is being mapped from $P_2(R)$ and $F^m$ is being mapped from W?

Comment: Every linear map has associated a matrix, once we fix a basis on the domain and a basis on the target. The matrix you have written corresponds to the linear map $P_2[\mathbb{R}]\rightarrow P_2[\mathbb{R}], f(x)\rightarrow f'(x)+f(0)x$ with respect to the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}.$ Note that $W$ is the subspace of $P_2[\mathbb{R}]$ that goes to the vector $0$ (this is the kernel of the application). As you have said you can identify this linear map with the left-multiplication by the matrix. So, $W$ is the subspace mapped to $0.$ I don't know what you mean by $F^n,F^m.$